# Google Play services not working

Tags: root-access, samsung

I just rooted my S4 using KingoRoot. After rooting I am not able to access any of the Google services.

When I try to open any of the Google services, it says

> Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped

I am not able to open any app. When I try to open an app, it says,

> [App Name] has stopped.

I tried clearing cache data of Google Play Services, reinstalled and reinstalled it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to factory reset your device from recovery.

Download GApps from xda-developers. (You need to search it xda). Download pico or mini version of gapps.

Copy zip file on your device and flash it via recovery.

Mostly, this will work. If not, then try to switch from dalvik to ART or ART to dalvik. (This applies only if you have 4.4+ Android OS)